# Accidentally deleted Applications link in Favorites in Finder

Tags: finder, applications

I accidentally deleted the Applications link in Favorites in Finder.  (I dragged it into the Terminal hoping to do a cd to the Applications folder---not that that matters.)

How can I restore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Finder → Preferences (⌘,) → Sidebar and check Applications.

[image]